# Native To/From Managed Function Type Debugging in C++/CLR

Tags: c++, clr, native, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to get a function named `CreateCircle(std::string color, int radius)` that returns a type of `CircleNative*` to compile/work within a Native To/from Managed Wrapper class implementation.

I'm new to C++ and I'm not understanding the correct structure to get the compiler to accept the `CircleNative*` type. Can you please assist me with debugging?

I receive the following errors:

```
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    ShapeFactoryWrapper 

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    ShapeFactoryWrapper 
..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.h

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   ShapeFactoryWrapper 
..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.h

Error   C2789   'ShapeFactoryWrapper::CircleNative': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized  ShapeFactoryWrapper ..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.cpp  

Error   C2039   'CreateCircle': is not a member of 'ShapeFactoryWrapper'    
..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.cpp

Error   C2065   '_private': undeclared identifier   ShapeFactoryWrapper ..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.cpp

Error   C2227   left of '->CreateCircle' must point to class/struct/union/generic type  ShapeFactoryWrapper 
..\ShapeFactoryWrapper.cpp
```

**ShapeFactoryWrapper.h**

```
#include <string>

class ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate;

class _declspec(dllexport) ShapeFactoryWrapper
{
    private: 
        ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate* _private;
    public:
        ShapeFactoryWrapper(); 
    public:
        ~ShapeFactoryWrapper();
    public:
        const CircleNative * CreateCircle(std::string color, int radius);
    public:
        void SetCircleProperties();
};

struct CircleNative
{
    std::string color;
    int radius;
};
```

**ShapeFactoryWrapper.ccp**

```
#using "ShapeFactory.dll"

#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
#include "ShapeFactoryWrapper.h"

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

class ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate
{
    private: 
        msclr::auto_gcroot<ShapeFactory^> client;
    public:
        ~ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate()
        {
        }

        ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate()
        {
            client = gcnew ShapeFactory;
        }

        void ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate::SetCircleProperties()
        {
            CircleNative* native = NULL;
            CircleManaged^ managed = gcnew CircleManaged();

            client->SetCircleProperties(managed);
        }

        const CircleNative * ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate::CreateCircle(std::string color, int radius)
        {
            CircleNative * native = new CircleNative();
            native->color = "Green";
            native->radius = 50;
            return native;
        }

};

ShapeFactoryWrapper::ShapeFactoryWrapper()
{
    _private = new ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate();
}

void ShapeFactoryWrapper::SetCircleProperties()
{
    _private->SetCircleProperties();
}

const CircleNative * ShapeFactoryWrapper::CreateCircle(std::string color, int radius)
{
    return _private->CreateCircle("Blue", 40);
}

ShapeFactoryWrapper::~ShapeFactoryWrapper()
{
    delete _private;
}
```

**ShapeFactory.cs**

```
public class ShapeFactory
{
    public void SetCircleProperties(ref CircleManaged circleManaged)
    {
        circleManaged.color = "Green";
        circleManaged.radius = 50;
    }
}

public class CircleManaged
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public int radius { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why you have std::string in the wrapper interface? do you expect C# understand std::string?

Comment: That's beside the point.. I did not add any string marshaling to this example as it's not pertinent to the question. The errors stem from the C++ .cpp and .h files not the C#.

Comment: The question really relates to the CircleNative* type where C++ seems to assume it's an int as seen in Error C4430 above. I'm trying to determine the correct way to call a function from the ShapeFactoryWrapper/ShapeFactoryWrapperPrivate class with the return type of CircleNative* so that I may easily create new native circle types but can't figure out the correct syntax/formulating of the C++ class. My eventual goal is to send the CircleNative* or a CircleManaged^ created  and returned from the CreateCircle function over to the C#.

Comment: For one thing you use `CircleNative` in `ShapeFactoryWrapper` before you declare it. Either move the declaration of `CircleNative` above the declaration of `ShapeFactoryWrapper` or use a forward declaration.

Comment: Thank you Walter, that was it! Silly mistake on my part.